# Java Apache http client

Tags: java, apache, http, cookie, client

Как с помощью Apache http client мне принять сессию и потом ее отправлять?
Приветствуются код с комментариями!

Comment: вопрос не совсем корректный. Сессию вы никак принять и передать не можете. Сессия храниться на сервере. Вы можете только передать идентификатор сессии с помощью Cookie или параметров адресной строки, чтобы сервер мог идентифицировать Вас и связать с сессией на сервере. Задача сводится к принятию и отправке Cookie. У вас были какие-либо попытки принять cookie в ответе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Сессия**, насколько я понимаю, это "соединение" между клиентом и сервером устанавливаемое на определенное время при помощи cookie, за которое клиент может отправить на сервер (в большинстве случаев) сколько угодно запросов.

**Cookie**, это небольшие блоки текстовой информации, которые сервер посылает клиенту для сохранения в файлах cookies. И потом могут быть переданы как часть заголовка HTTP([Headers](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8_HTTP)).

```
/* Инициализация */
    HttpClient http = null;
    CookieStore httpCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    //Устанавливаем хранилище кук
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCookieStore(httpCookieStore);
    http = builder.build();

    /* Делаем запрос */
    HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
    try {
        httpResponse = http.execute(httpRequest);
    } catch (Throwable error) {throw new RuntimeException(error);}
```

Если нужно изменить куки, сначала получаем, а потом по схеме выше сетим их в билдер.

```
/* Получаем куки  */
    httpCookieStore.getCookies();
```

Надеюсь это поможет.